# Difficulty hiding a span per a body class within WordPress

Tags: posts, css

I am trying to hide a span class as per the CSS class within the body tag.

Here is the HTML I am trying to hide:

```
<span class='efav-span'><img src="">Content here</span>
```

And the body tag is this:

```
<body class="post-template-default single single-post postid-5613 single-format-standard wp-custom-logo wp-embed-responsive cookies-not-set post-image-above-header post-image-aligned-center no-sidebar nav-float-right fluid-header separate-containers active-footer-widgets-0 header-aligned-left dropdown-hover" itemtype="https://schema.org/Blog" itemscope>
```

So what I thought would easily work is this:

```
.single.efav-span {display: none}
```

But oddly it doesn't?

I want that span to be hidden on ALL regular WordPress Posts.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was simple:

```
.single .efav-span {display: none}
```

add spacing to each element